# changes if using import instead of same package

Tags: java, import, package

Today I wrote an exam and there was this question, which lines of code won't work if we write `import countries.*;` instead of `package countries;` in the `TestCountry` class. Here's the two classes:

```
package countries;

public class Country {
    private String name;
    private int population;
    boolean isEuropean;
    public double area;
    protected Country[] neighbors;

    protected boolean inEurope() {
        return this.isEuropean;
    }

    private void updatePopulation(int newBorns) {
        this.population += newBorns;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String str ="";
        for (int i=0; i<this.neighbors.length; i++){
            str += neighbors[i].name+"\n";
        }
        return str;
    }


    Countries[] getNeighbors() {
        return this.neighbors;
    }

    String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

And

```
import countries.*;
// package countries;

    public class TestCountry extends Country {
    public void run() {

    System.out.println(name);
    System.out.println(population);
    System.out.println(isEuropean);
    System.out.println(inEurope());
    System.out.println(area);

    System.out.println(toString());
    updatePopulation(100);
    System.out.println(getNeighbors());
    System.out.println(getName());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        TestCountry o1 = new TestCountry();
        o1.run();
    }
}
```

Of course I tried it out and found out that the following lines wouldn't work anymore (if we outcomment `package countries;` and write `import countries.*;` instead):

```
System.out.println(isEuropean);
System.out.println(getNeighbors());
System.out.println(getName());
```

Can someone explain me why they don't work and what `import countries.*;` exactly does?

Comment: Without modifiers, `isEuropean`, `getName()` are having default scope also called **package** scope. Your test was no longer in the same package as the class therefore it can only access `public` and `protected` members (protected because it is subclass of `Country`.
See this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you have not set the scope of the  `String getName()`, `getNeighbors()` method(where it can be accessible), so they have `default package scope`i.e they can be used within the same package.same is with the variable `isEuropean`.so you can not use them in another package.
But all the `protected` member of your `Countries` class can be accessible since your `test class` is extending `Countries` class

**Access Levels**

```
+---------------+-------+---------+----------+-------+
| modifiers     | class | package | subclass | world |
+---------------+-------+---------+----------+-------+
| Public        |   Y   |    Y    |    Y     |   Y   |
+---------------+-------+---------+----------+-------+
| Protected     |   Y   |    Y    |    Y     |   N   |
+-----------------------+---------+----------+-------+
| Private       |   Y   |    N    |    N     |   N   |
+---------------+-------+---------+----------+-------+
| No Modifiers  |   Y   |    Y    |    N     |   N   |
+---------------+-------+---------+----------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(getNeighbors());
```